# Should I plant Bilva in my home?

Tags: shiva, worship, plants

I have planted a Bilva (Bel) plant in my lawn whose leaves I use for Shiva pooja. Some of the priests said that Bel plant should not be planted in the house. Instead, it should be migrated to a temple.

Is it true?

Comment: Related: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/873/36

Comment: The siva purana tells where to plant Bilva vriksha. you can plant on all four sides in your home/plot

Answer (score 5):

In Hinduism the Bilva tree is sacred.

> It can be planted anywhere. Bilva leaves and fruits have very high medicinal value especially to cure stomach related problems. However, while planting Bilva tree it may be kept in mind that there is danger from falling fruits which are very hard and heavy and can cause injury.

Source: this [link](https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110922025431AA4LlDU), which has a detailed explanation.

Comment: Yahoo Answers is not an acceptable reference on this site.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Can you support your answer with a reference to any Purana?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan The most upvoted answer (appearing on the top) which is given in the link is well researched, well explained with proper references. It could be copied and pasted here; stack exchange does not check plagiarism; but giving the link means paying respect to the original author who took the pain to explain. Do we have a constraint of source (like: yahoo or quora links cannot be posted) or do we consider/appreciate the quality of answer from any source (with references)? If we have the constraint we may discuss in meta.

Comment: @JavaTechnical things are explained in Kurma Purana, Vayu Purana and Shiva Purana. I will check if text is available online to reference. Also I edited to add one thing in my answer.

Comment: @JavaTechnical Shiva Purana mentions how the usage of Bilva, with its scientific and medical properties, is of great advantage. The 22nd Chapter narrates, "The trifoliate Bilva Patra is so sacred to Lord Shiva & is therefore a symbol of the Lord. Adored by all the Gods, its importance is difficult for anyone to comprehend. The sacred tree can only be known to a limited extent. Sacred sites of this Earth can only find their place at the root of this tree. Those who meditate upon Lord Mahadeva in form of His linga at the root of Bilva obtain Moksha & get purified souls by attaining Shiva".

Comment: "The most upvoted answer (appearing on the top) which is given in the link is well researched, well explained with proper references." If it's well researched with references, then go to those links and they'e a reputable source and if so cite the information contained in those links, rather than just copying and pasting an answer from Yahoo Answers. "It could be copied and pasted here; stack exchange does not check plagiarism" Actually, plagiarism is not allowed on Hinduism.SE, and pure copy-paste answers without saying anything in your own words, even when a link is provided, is not allowed.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan The Yahoo answer accumulated the information from all sources to a single place, that's why I referred it. Ok, please make it clear if Yahoo and Quora answers can be referred here (Hinduism.SE) or not?

Comment: @arin1405 Also, the first quote in your answer is irrelevant to the question.  The question is about where the Bilva tree can be planted, not why it's holy.  That would be more relevant in this earlier question: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/873/36 By the way, saying "chapter 22" of the Shiva Purana doesn't make much sense, because the Shiva Purana is divided into a bunch of sections (Samhitas) each of which is divided into chapters.

Comment: @arin1405 No, thinks like Yahoo Answers, Quora, forums, etc. are not acceptable references on this site.  You should cite a reputable source, preferably scripture.  In any case, if you want to discuss this further you should post a question on Meta.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Yes, we need to clear things on meta if any quality answer can be referred from other forum which is well referenced. When I answer a technical question in Stack Overflow, the reference is done to original software document available online. But this forum is related to religion and philosophy. A single sanskrit stotram can be explained in many ways. An incident can be researched from different angles. Its difficult to verify if an online source is really *reliable* for this aspect and also if we really need to ignore references of some quality explanation in other forums.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Yes, I missed the Samhita. As the [source](https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110718022121AAlKm1B) mentions it from vidyesvarasamhita in a recension where [vidyesvarasamhita](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiva_Purana) consists of 25 chapters.

Comment: @arin1405 OK, here's the relevant excerpt from chapter 22 of the Vidyeshwara Samhita of the Shiva Purana: http://gdurl.com/fGJi By the way, like I said you should take out the first quote in your answer, because it's irrelevant to the question of where the Bilva tree should be planted.  The Shiva Purana excerpt would also be irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan ok, I edited the answer by removing the spiritual explanation of Bilva tree.

Comment: @arin1405 By the way, I checked the links cited in the Yahoo answer.  None of them seem to discuss where you can plant the Bilva tree.  That part just seems to be this guy's opinion.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan do you know any link that explains the plantation area of Bilva tree? I doubt if Puranas put any restriction on it.

Answer (score 5):

Bilva tree is not normal tree. There are many Bilva trees in many jungles of India. There is no restriction that Bilva tree can not be planted at home. In hinduism, each home is a symbol of Shivalaya. Each father is a symbol of Shiva, Every mother is considered as pious and pure and respected as mother Parvati.

Blva tree is having pure effects. Many people just go to temple and put Bilva leaf on Shivalinga and just go out of temple. It is not true ritual.

### True ritual

is touch Bilva leaf to ShivaLingam , chant "**Bilvashatak** verses"

> Tridalam Trigunakaam, Trinetram cha triyayudham,
>   Trijanma pap samharama Ek bilvam shivarpanam

You can chant whole Bilvashatak or can chant only this verse. Now take that Bilva leaf and put it on head, touch it on eyes and take it with you for the day. Put it in your pocket of shirt and take it with you.

This single leaf will make your whole day "Peacefull and energatic", this is true ritual. This leaf has that power.

### No Restrictions in Hindu Scriptures

Bilva tree is a tree so it can plant itself like any other tree anywhere. Wind can transfer this tree's seed to somewhere and it can grow anywhere by itself. No need to fear to have it in home garden.

No Hindu scriptures states any restriction in Bilva tree. Priests may have told you because they have fear that this tree's energy is more. But you can have confidence in your self, and can ignore them.

It is in your garden , so it will not be publicly available, if it would be in temple then more people can use it, so priests may have some good intention. After all they are priests so they must have some good intention. But personally I will tell you not to fear.

Answer (score 3):

In any Purana nobody mentioned about where to grow trees. Growing Bilva Vriksha or nagavalli vrikasha, arjuna vriksha like many sacred trees is very good source of positive energy. Without any doubt in mind you just let it grow in your house. But remember they should not be in your north east side of your home.

Answer (score 0):

Bilva gtree is the tree of Lakshmi. It is stated in Sri Sukta: "Aditya varne tapasodi jaatho vanaspathihi **tha vriksho the bilvaha**; Thasya phalani thapasanuthanthu mayaantha rayaantha bhagya lakshmihi"

This is why it is so beloved to Shankara, because the bilva tree emenated from the tapas of Maha Lakshmi. It is indeed a very auspicious tree to have in the home and will banish all signs of poverty.

Comment: It's not bhagya laksmihi but " AdityavarNe tapaso.adhijAto vanaspatistava vR^ikSo.atha bilvaH |
tasya phalAni tapasAnudantumAyAntarAyAshcha bAhyA alakSmIH ||   आदित्यवर्णे तपसोऽधिजातो वनस्पतिस्तव वृक्षोऽथ बिल्वः ।
तस्य फलानि तपसानुदन्तु मायान्तरायाश्च बाह्या अलक्ष्मीः ॥