# Source book for story of Lohitansh/Lohitang

Tags: shiva, scripture

Recently, I saw a track going on in TV serial `Devo Ke Dev Mahadev` on LIfe OK channel. The track is about an ansha of Lord Shiva called Lohitansh, who was born from the blood of Shiva while he was teaching Tandava dance to Pushpadant. I wanted to know, which Purana/Scripture/Book actually contains this story?

Comment: Devon ke dev Mahadev showed the true story of Lohitang or Bhauma because Mangal/Mars is an very angry God in Navagraha and Lohitang also that and one day my mother told me the story of Lohitang which was shown in Devon ke dev Mahadev.

Comment: I know an another story of Lohitang. One day Lord Krishna was sleeping and Sudhama was protecting him. When Radha came to met with Krishna,Sudhama stopped her. She was very angry and she gave a curse to Sudhama that in his next birth,Sudhama will be a demon. In his next birth,Sudhama became Shankchur. Shankchur's wife was Goddess Tulsi and his friend was Lohitang or Angaraka.

Comment: devon ke dev mahadev's villan lohitang was made by the serial director.lohitang does not exist

Comment: @derek, I think Lohitang does exists as I have read some hindu script extract while googling where the name Lohitang was there but nothing else apart from that. I think Keshav might be right in the sense that it is another name for Mangal/Mars but the story is self created by the TV serial crew.

Comment: I am the hero of Devon ke dev Mahadev and I will tell you the true story of Lohitang. Our serial's company's director bought a sadhu baba in the shooting of Lohitang scenes. We shooted the scenes with reading the sadhu baba's Shiva's book. Our scenes were true

Comment: Hi @Ishan Thanks for your reply but can you please tell me the details about the book such as name of the book, publisher, publication year, etc.

Comment: In my opinion this is just a rehash of Jalandhar's character. Lohitang's real name is Bhauma he was a part of the Navgrahas. Yet when Ravana conquered the Navgrahas they did not show him conquering lohitang (Bhauma). Also Bhauma was the son of Visnu not Siva.

Answer (score 6):

Lohitanga, also known as Angaraka, Mangala, or Bhauma, is the god of the planet Mars.  The story of his birth is told in [this excerpt](http://gdurl.com/11Hj) from the Rudra Samhita of the Shiva Purana, although it differs significantly from the story told in "Devon Ke Dev Mahadev".  (TV serials tend to take quite a lot of artistic license.)  In this account, after the death of his first wife Shakti, Shiva is devastated so he engages in Tapasya (deep meditation) for several years.  Eventually he starts sweating out of exhaustion, and drops of sweat from his forehead fall onto the Earth, where they turn into a baby boy.  Since the boy was born on the earth, Bhumidevi the goddess of the earth raises the boy with Shiva's permission.  Thus the boy acquires the name Bhauma or son of Bhumidevi.  He then worships Shiva at Kashi (Varanasi) for a long time, and as a result Shiva makes him into the planet Mars.

By the way, from what I can gather, "Devon Ke Dev Mahadeva" also depicts Bhauma being raised by the demon Andhakasura.  I don't think there's any scriptural basis for that, but it's interesting to note that Andhakasura does have one connection to Bhauma: just as Bhauma was born out of Shiva's sweat, Andhakasura is said to be born out of Parvati's sweat.  (Another thing that was born from Parvati's sweat was the Bilva tree, as I discuss in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/876/36).)

Comment: I know the story of Mangal/Mars, but that was a totally different track. He never fought or had any bad feelings for Shiva. Rather, he went for doing penance of Shiva. Even, the motherly love of Earth couldnot stop him from doing the penance. Lohitang character is either created by the TV serial on their own or there is some other scriptual reference. Ofcouse the name bears the meaning which has body of color of blood which brings him near to being mars as that is also a red planet. However, googling it, I could only find the name Lohitang in some texts but not any associated story.

Comment: @Aby Well, the story begins the same on Devon ke Dev Mahadev: http://www.tellyupdates.com/devon-ke-dev-mahadev-25th-july-2014-written-episode-update/ "Devi prithvi comes and says, this child is born on me then can i take this child. Mahadev says to mata, Yes devi parvati, devi prithvi will take care of Rohitansh."  So I think the creators just made up the part about him being led astray by Andhakasura and fighting Shiva.