# How to worship a Bilva tree

Tags: shiva, temple, worship

Bilva tree is situated in a Devi temple complex.
How to worship the Bilva tree.

Comment: Do you want to know how to worship bilva tree or how to worship Shiva with Bilva leaves?

Comment: You may find [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/873/what-is-the-significance-of-bel-leaves-in-shiva-worship) helpful.

Comment: Bilva Tree is auspicious, it should be worshipped in same manner as of Lord Shiva. Root of tree represents Lord Shiva. Worship root of tree, water it, offer flowers and light lamp. Jai Bholenath. According to Shiva Purana.

Answer (score 2):

**Bilva treated as Lord Shiva’s Tree**

> Lakshmyaascha stana utpannam Mahaadeva sadaa priyam,
>
> Bilva vriksham prayachchhaami eka bilvam Shivaarpanam.
>
> Darshanam bilva vrikshasya sparshanam paapanaashanam,
>
> Aghorapaapasamhaaram eka bilvam shivarpanam.

Born from the bosom of Goddess Lakshmi, the Bilva tree is ever dear to Mahadeva. So I ask this tree to offer a Bilva leaf to Lord Shiva. To have darshan of the Bilva tree, and to touch it, frees one from sin. The most terrible karma is destroyed when a Bilva leaf is offered to Lord Shiva.
Sri Bilva Shtakam (v. 6–7)

> According to the **Shiva Purana (7 AD) the Bilva tree is the manifest form of Lord Shiva himself**, while all the great tirthas (pilgrimage places) are said to reside at its base. One who worships the shivalingam while sitting under the Bilva, claims this great epic, attains the state of Shiva. Washing the head by this tree is said to be the equivalent of bathing in all the sacred rivers.

One who performs Bilva pooja with flowers and incense achieves Shiva loka, the abode of pure consciousness, and has happiness and prosperity bestowed upon them. The lighting of the deepak (lamp) before this tree bestows knowledge and enables the devotee to merge in Lord Shiva. The Shiva Purana also claims that if the devotee removes the new leaves from one of the branches of that tree and worships the tree with them, they will be freed from vice, while one who feeds a devotee under the Bilva will grow in virtue.